# in org-mode, how to remove a link?

Tags: org-mode

How do I remove an existing hyperlink without having to wade in and manually delete a bunch of brackets? When I try to `org-insert-link` and just delete the existing link, I get `Lisp error: (error "Empty link")`.

I want to remove the link and preserve the text (i.e. the description).

Comment: Starting with Org mode version 9.4 (commit 6d62c76d2), deleting the link part does not give an error any longer: `C-c C-l` and deleting the existing link works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following elisp function will take a link around the current point as recognised by `org-bracket-link-regexp`, so either `[[Link][Description]]` or `[[Link]]`, and replace it by `Description` in the first case or `Link` in the second case.

New version: for org 9.3 or newer (also added `save-excursion` as in the answer of @Chris)

```lisp
(defun afs/org-replace-link-by-link-description ()
    "Replace an org link by its description or if empty its address"
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
              (description
               (if (match-end 2) 
                   (org-match-string-no-properties 2)
                 (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))
          (apply 'delete-region remove)
          (insert description)))))
```

Alternatively the following elisp function will do such a replacement on all links in the buffer or region:

```lisp
(defun afs/org-replace-all-links-by-description (&optional start end)
  "Find all org links and replace by their descriptions."
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p) (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (point-min) (point-max))))
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region start end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward org-link-bracket-re nil t)
        (replace-match (match-string-no-properties 
                        (if (match-end 2) 2 1)))))))
```

The above is for org 9.4, where `org-match-string-no-properities` has been obseleted in favour of `match-string-no-properties`.

Old version: before org 9.3

```lisp
(defun afs/org-replace-link-by-link-description ()
    "Replace an org link by its description or if empty its address"
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-regexp org-bracket-link-regexp 1)
      (let ((remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
        (description (if (match-end 3) 
                 (org-match-string-no-properties 3)
                 (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))
    (apply 'delete-region remove)
    (insert description))))
```

In org version 9.3 `org-bracket-link-regexp` was obsoleted, but aliased to the new `org-link-bracket-re`.  The new regexp is documented in `ol.el` as

```lisp
org-link-bracket-re
(rx (seq "[["
         ;; URI part: match group 1.
         (group
          (one-or-more
               (or (not (any "[]\\"))
               (and "\\" (zero-or-more "\\\\") (any "[]"))
               (and (one-or-more "\\") (not (any "[]"))))))
         "]"
         ;; Description (optional): match group 2.
         (opt "[" (group (+? anything)) "]")
         "]"))
```

so the second group now matches the description of the link if present.

Comment: That's a very neat compact solution! I updated my answer to support `[[LINK]]` format org links too. I learned about `match-beginning` and `match-end` from your answer.

Comment: I had to change `3` to `2` in @Andrew Swan [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10714/25547). I am assuming the current version of regexp search returns only 2 matches: the link and the description. Maybe this change happened through numerous upgrades of `org-mode` since 2015. I am running Org mode 9.3.7 on GNU Emacs 27.1. With that change, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Raj Many thanks.  Code updated.  This changed in version 9.3.

Comment: I want to do this on all links in the selection; How to adapt this?

Comment: @HappyFace I have now added a function to do this.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to add this to the answer from @Andrew, but it was too long for a comment...

I really liked his solution, except that it moved the cursor. (Technically I guess it moved the point. Anyway...) Fortunately, it was easy to add `save-excursion` to avoid that:

```el
(defun afs/org-replace-link-by-link-description ()
  "Replace an org link by its description or if empty its address"
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-regexp org-bracket-link-regexp 1)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
              (description (if (match-end 3) 
                               (org-match-string-no-properties 3)
                             (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))
          (apply 'delete-region remove)
          (insert description)))))
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a solution which avoids using custom parsing with regexes and directly uses the built-in `org-element` API:

```el
(defun org-link-delete-link ()
  "Remove the link part of an org-mode link at point and keep
only the description"
  (interactive)
  (let ((elem (org-element-context)))
    (if (eq (car elem) 'link)
        (let* ((content-begin (org-element-property :contents-begin elem))
               (content-end  (org-element-property :contents-end elem))
               (link-begin (org-element-property :begin elem))
               (link-end (org-element-property :end elem)))
          (if (and content-begin content-end)
              (let ((content (buffer-substring-no-properties content-begin content-end)))
                (delete-region link-begin link-end)
                (insert content)))))))
```

Comment: Can you add how to bind your command to a key so it's sufficient for novices?

Comment: This seems to delete white spaces after the link. Any idea how to keep them?

Comment: I want to do this on all links in the selection; How to adapt this?

Comment: @Timm If you query `(org-element-property :post-blank elem)` you can get the number of trailing spaces after the link. Then you could choose to "reinsert" them when you replace the element.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest may be to place the cursor before the link, then type `C-M-space` (`mark-sexp`), which will mark the entire link. Then delete it by typing a backspace (if you use `delete-selection-mode`) or `C-w`.

Comment: This seems to delete the entire link, but I want to remove the link and preserve the text (i.e. the description).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question.

Comment: To the downvoters out there: The question was ambiguous when I answered it. It has been edited since then, removing the ambiguity. I do leave the answer up, though, since it still seems the easiest way to delete the entire link, description and all.

Comment: This frequently does not select the whole link. Some `]]` stay around after deleting the selection. This sometimes works in the same document at the same link and sometimes it doesn't. When I `org-toggle-link-display` after selection, sometimes the whole link is selected, sometimes only the caption text. Also with the expand-region package, sometimes if have to execute `er/expand-region` 4 times until text outside the link is selected, sometimes only to times even though I follow exactly the same steps beginning with Emacs restart.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's quite odd, I think, unless of course either the link text or the link itself contains unbalanced delimiters. I can't think of a reasonable explanation. (Which doesn't mean one can't be found.)

Comment: Very odd for sure. No, the links are fine. When I toggle link display I can verify that. When I run Emacs with no config I wasn't able to reproduce, but when I step by step load the settings it happens sometimes. It seems to happen much more often with Emacsclient than with Emacs. I don't expect you to provide a solution, but after wasting 2 hours, writing about it helps sorting my thoughts. ..

Answer (score 4):

Call this command when the point is anywhere after the first `[[` brackets of an org-link (or anywhere on/after an hyper-linked org-link).

An org link will be deleted if it is of the format `[[LINK][DESCRIPTION]]` or `[[LINK]]` in an `org-mode` buffer; else nothing will happen.

For safety, the discarded LINK from org-link is saved to the `kill-ring` in the event a need arises to use that link elsewhere.

```el
(defun my/org-delete-link ()
  "Replace an org link of the format [[LINK][DESCRIPTION]] with DESCRIPTION.
If the link is of the format [[LINK]], delete the whole org link.

In both the cases, save the LINK to the kill-ring.

Execute this command while the point is on or after the hyper-linked org link."
  (interactive)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (let ((search-invisible t) start end)
      (save-excursion
        (when (re-search-backward "\\[\\[" nil :noerror)
          (when (re-search-forward "\\[\\[\\(.*?\\)\\(\\]\\[.*?\\)*\\]\\]" nil :noerror)
            (setq start (match-beginning 0))
            (setq end   (match-end 0))
            (kill-new (match-string-no-properties 1)) ; Save the link to kill-ring
            (replace-regexp "\\[\\[.*?\\(\\]\\[\\(.*?\\)\\)*\\]\\]" "\\2" nil start end)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all links in the selection:

```lisp
(defun night/org-remove-link-to-desc-at-point ()
    "Replace an org link by its description or if empty its address"
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
              (description
               (if (match-end 2)
                   (org-match-string-no-properties 2)
                 (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))
          (apply 'delete-region remove)
          (insert description)))))

(defun night/org-remove-link-to-desc (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-mark-and-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (re-search-forward org-link-bracket-re end t)
      (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
      (night/org-remove-link-to-desc-at-point))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This very quick and very dirty macro would be one way, not the best way:

```
(fset 'my/org-remove-link
   [?\M-a delete delete ?\M-x ?z ?a ?p ?- ?t ?o ?- ?c ?h ?a ?r return ?\[ ?\C-e backspace backspace ?\C-x])
```