# How to delete a link in org mode in spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, org-link, hyperlinks

I was trying to delete a link and replace it with the description in org mode. And I thought there would be a command to do it. But I could not find one.

There is a solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10707/in-org-mode-how-to-remove-a-link). But the question is dated. So, I thought I would ask again.

Is not there a built-in solution to remove the link but retain the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `C-c C-l` on the link and `C-a C-k` in the minibuffer to delete the link part will do it..

This used to produce an error before Org mode version 9.4, but it no longer does (see commit https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/6d62c76d2).

Comment: @NickD Thanks. It works. Though, a bit cumbersome. I wish there were a one command solution to the problem.

Comment: Please thank @nichijou. He provided the answer: I just chased down the commit. As for a one-command solution, I doubt that there is much demand for it, but you can always write a function that does  what the answer indicates and bind it to a key of your choice.

Comment: ... or you could define a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html), [name it, bind it to a key and save it for future sessions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html).

Comment: @NickD please teach me how did you locate the relevant commit.

Comment: I figured it was a change in `lisp/ol.el` since it was a change in link behavior.   In my clone of the Org mode git repo, I  then did `git log --oneline -- lisp/ol.el`. It was a bit of luck that I guessed right about `lisp/ol.el`, but the thirteenth commit from the top said "ol.el: Allow to remove the link part of a link" - bingo! I then took the SHA1 of it and found it in the  "official" git repo (it's always at the URL in the link above - you just have to replace the commit ID with the one you want).

Comment: @NickD learned a lot, thanks!

Comment: @nichijou Thanks. I had two @ mentions in my earlier comment.  Apparently, that was not allowed. And your name got deleted accidentally. I will be more careful.

Comment: @NickD I earlier had access to an emacs implementation that used Doom Emacs. There used to be `org/remove-link` (I hope, I am getting the name right.) function. But my current spacemacs does not provide that. I have updated spacemacs to the latest version. But still can not find that function. Any workaround

Comment: I know nothing about doom or spacemacs. There is no such function  in standard Org mode (it would probably have a prefix of `org-link` if it existed: do `C-h org-link- TAB` to see completions; AFAICT, there is nothing to remove links). But as I said above, you can write a little function or a macro to do it, based on @nichijou's answer.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10707/in-org-mode-how-to-remove-a-link